# PHP - Repetitive code for generating HTML

Tags: php, html, arrays

I have the following **Array**s

```
$elemento = 
["title"=> //Level 1
    ["iSh*t","text-center",40,"red"] //Level 2
];
$elemento2 = 
["row"=>[ //Level 1
        ["col"=>[  //Level 2
                ["sm-6"=>[  //Level 3
                        ["text"=>  //Level 4
                            ["Lorem ipsum sit amet","text-center",16,"blue"] //Level 5
                        ]
                    ]
                ],
                ["sm-6"=>[  //Level 3
                        ["text"=>  //Level 4
                            ["Lorem ipsum sit amet","text-center",16,"blue"] //Level 5
                        ]
                    ]
                ],
                ["sm-6"=>[  //Level 3 
                        ["row"=>[  //Level 4
                                ["col"=>[  //Level 5
                                        ["sm-6"=>[  //Level 6
                                                ["title" =>  //Level 7
                                                    ["Lorem ipsum sit amet","text-center",16,"blue"]  //Level 8
                                                ]
                                            ]
                                        ]
                                    ]   
                                ],
                                ["col"=>[  //Level 5
                                        ["sm-6"=>[  //Level 6
                                                ["title" =>  //Level 7
                                                    ["Lorem ipsum sit amet","text-center",16,"blue"]  //Level 8
                                                ]
                                            ]
                                        ],
                                        ["sm-6"=>[  //Level 6
                                                ["title" =>  //Level 7
                                                    ["Lorem ipsum sit amet","text-center",16,"blue"]  //Level 8
                                                ]
                                            ]
                                        ]
                                    ]   
                                ]
                            ]   
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]   
        ]
    ]
];
```

I want to create a function than iterates on **every** "level" of my array no matter how many "levels".

Now, I have a function but, yes I know it's not optimized, but I just wanna see how can I make this work.

```
public function toHTML($superobj,$html){
    $html = "<div class=\"bloque\"><div class=\"c-c\">";
    XO::_html_get($superobj,$html);
    $html = $html."</div></div>";
    return $html;
}
private function _html_get($superobj,&$html){
    foreach ($superobj as $i => $val) {
        foreach ($val as $i => $val) {
            switch ($i) {
                case 'title':
                    $html = $html."<h1 class=\"".$val[1]."\" style=\"font-size:".$val[2]."px;color:".$val[3]."\">".$val[0]."</h1>";
                    break;
                case 'text':
                    $html = $html."<p class=\"".$val[1]."\">".$val[0]."</p>";
                    break;
                case 'image':
                    $html = $html."<img src=\"".$val[0]."\" class=\"".$val[1]."\">";
                    break;
                case 'row':
                    $html = $html."<div class=\"row\">";
                    foreach ($val as $i => $val) {
                        foreach ($val as $i => $val) {
                            if ($i == "columna") {
                                foreach ($val as $i => $val) {
                                    $html = $html."<div class=\"col-".array_keys($val)[0]."\">";
                                        foreach ($val as $i => $val) {
                                            foreach ($val as $i => $val) {
                                                foreach ($val as $i => $val) {
                                                    if ($i == "texto") {
                                                        $html = $html."<p class=\"".$val[1]."\">".$val[0]."</p>";
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    $html = $html."</div>";
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    $html = $html."</div>";
                    break;
                case 'row':
                    $html = $html."";
                    break;
                case 'div':
                    $html = $html."";
                    break;
                case 'button':
                    $html = $html."";
                    break;
                case 'link':
                    $html = $html."";
                    break;
                default:
                    # code...
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now, "working" is, but if I add more levels to level 3 (sm-6) won't work cause the function is not prepared for that..

> I know this way is **not** optimized and/or recommended, but...
>
> ### How can I do this? :)

If you wanna recommend me other way to do this, please don't recommend me frameworks, even if that makes the work and tasks easy, **I will not learn anything**, I love "hand" code.

Comment: You can use recursion
https://lornajane.net/posts/2012/php-recursive-function-example-factorial-numbers

Comment: Yes, I was wonder myself about it. :) Thank you!

Comment: It would be nice if you come back here and present your recursive solution for others to learn.

Comment: @ArturR.Czechowski I'm just learning about recursive functions but is not easy anyway. It depends on which situation you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very simplified structure for what you are trying to achieve is:

```
function recursiveIteration ($array, &$html){

    foreach ($array as $key => $value){

        if (is_array($value)){
            recursiveIteration($value, $html);
        }
        else {
            $html .= intendedHtmlForThisItem($key);
        }
    }
}
```

Which allows to to create as many levels as you want.

Comment: Yes, but there's some array keys to take, like "text","row","col", and "sm-6" for those the result is diferent. :/

Comment: This is just a basic idea of how to do it recursively. If you need to have some keys treated specially you can still have in if/switch for them at the top of the loop, and fall back to the recursive if otherwise

Comment: Yea, I'm looking for the best performance posible on hand code. I know it's possible.